# Parsing HTML Element By Element at Java

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have an HTML file:

```html
<div>
   DIV1
    <div>
      DIV2
       <div>
          DIV3
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to parse that HTML. However I don't want to get whole parsed HTML as a string:

```
DIV1 DIV2 DIV3
```

I would like to get values element by element but none of them duplicated. I mean I don't want that:

When you get first div's value it is:

```
DIV1 DIV2 DIV3
```

Seconds div's value:

```
DIV2 DIV3
```

Third div's value:

```
DIV3
```

The result that I don't want is:

```
DIV1 DIV2 DIV3
DIV2 DIV3
DIV3
```

I want that result:

```
DIV1
DIV2
DIV2
```

I will apply some procedure to them and I don't want duplicated values as well. I want to use a Java parser to solve my problem. I've considered to use Jsoup but you get entire HTML parsed when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do a [pre order depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for all text nodes in an HTML document. Luckily most parsing libraries including XML  ones will give you all the nodes in pre order as an iterator.

I recommend you use Jericho and call [getNodeIterator()](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/Segment.html#getNodeIterator()) and just check to see if its a text node and if it is you print it out. Nootice the link has example code but I will paste it here for your convenience:

```
 for (Iterator<Segment> nodeIterator=segment.getNoteIterator(); nodeIterator.hasNext();) {
   Segment nodeSegment=nodeIterator.next();
   if (nodeSegment instanceof Tag) {
     Tag tag=(Tag)nodeSegment;
     // HANDLE TAG
     // Uncomment the following line to ensure each tag is valid XML:
     // writer.write(tag.tidy()); continue;
   } else if (nodeSegment instanceof CharacterReference) {
     CharacterReference characterReference=(CharacterReference)nodeSegment;
     // HANDLE CHARACTER REFERENCE
     // Uncomment the following line to decode all character references instead of copying them verbatim:
     // characterReference.appendCharTo(writer); continue;
   } else {
     // HANDLE PLAIN TEXT
   }
   // unless specific handling has prevented getting to here, simply output the segment as is:
   //writer.write(nodeSegment.toString());
 }
```

In the `// HANDLE CHARACTER REFERENCE` and `// HANDLE PLAIN TEXT` are where you want to add your string appending code.